# Галерея на JavaScript, советы - реализация

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, lightbox

День добрый, столкнулся с проблемой такой что меня загрузили сделать JS для просмотра фотографий =(

[image]

1) При клике на маленькое изображение подменяется картинка в среднем размере.
2) При клике на среднее изображение срабатывает пусть через тот-же LightBox, и изображение открывается в большом окне.
3) Исходя из скриншота необходимо сделать листалку в лево и в право.

Я не прошу написать за меня скрипт. Просто подскажите какие скрипты можно связать или взять на UpGrade ну или хотя-бы дайте совет по быстрой реализации, разбирался бы сам - но горят сроки сдачи сайта =(

Comment: если горят сроки, то вот лучшая на мой взгляд галерея на jQuery - `[Фоторама](http://fotoramajs.com/)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А разбираться и не нужно. За Вас уже все готово. Нужно только в гугл вписать "**галереи jquery**" и будет Вам счастье.

[ВОТ](http://www.peaxl.ru/featured/luchshie-jquery-galerei-i-slajdery/), что я нашел в гугле.

Там даже есть точно такая же как у Вас  на картинке. Называется "Featured Content Slider"

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо =)